# LDAP modify replace attribute with NULL value

Tags: ldap

im suppose to try to replace some attribute value of LDAP data into NULL value, but I cant seem to get it to work using LDIF format.

I tried various format.. all seems to return me an error.

Here are those format:

```
dn: some..RDN
changeType: modify
replace: data
data:

or 

dn: some..RDN
changeType: modify
replace: data
```

Can anyone advise me how to replace data attribute value to NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dn: some..RDN 
changeType: modify 
replace: data
-
```

That is; a line with just a -.

Comment: This is what I got

`ldapmodify: no attributes to change or add`

Answer (score 0):

Beware that MS LDAP API (wldap32.dll) has an [old bug](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.active.directory.interfaces/browse_thread/thread/9c13fe85e520f0b4/820a136e032946e9) with empty values which makes it hardly possible to wort with with empty values. AFAIK, is not fixed yet. So even if LDIF is ok, there might be a problem at API level.

What LDIF tool you use?

Comment: using OpenLdap tool like ldapmodify

Comment: try using this:

dn: some..RDN 
changeType: modify 
replace: data
data:
-